# PHP/HTML .. JS? JQ? [CodeIgniter] custom image uploader - UI For Selecting A File

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I have a function in controller for uploading files to FTP and it's working fine. 
All I need now is a way to pass the file location and filename in a user-friendly way from codeigniter view into the controller.

Is there a way of doing it without using CI's  `form_open_multipart()` or any pre-made methods, but simply adding a file browser which would save file location and filename in 2 different variables? Call me old-fashioned or whatever, but I simply don't want to use `open_multipart` and rewrite everything just so I could do this one seemingly simple action.

Maybe something with JQuery or Javascript? I'am not hugely advanced on these.

TL;DR
I need a way to implement simple UI for selecting a file and storing it's *location* as well as *file-name* in PHP variable(-s).

EDIT:

Currently what I'am trying to do is use this form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadToFtp" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input  name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

to call this PHP function:

```
function uploadToFtp(){

            $destination=base_url().'images';

            $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  
            echo $file_name; 
            echo "$destination/$file_name";


             if (move_uploaded_file ($file_name , "$destination/$file_name" )) {echo 'OK';} else {echo 'Nope.';}
```

However this **doesn't work** (returns 'Nope'), even thought `$file_name` and `$destination` definitely store correct data.

`var_dump($_FILES)` doesn't give any clue neither:

> array (size=1)   'userfile' => 
>       array (size=5)
>         'name' => string 'vlcsnap-2015-11-02-00h20m03s307.png' (length=35)
>         'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
>         'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\php7F4D.tmp' (length=23)
>         'error' => int 0
>         'size' => int 366031

PS. Just to be clear, PHP function gets called AND can assess the data of file which is being uploaded *correctly*, however for some reason move_uploaded_file() returns FALSE.

EDIT2:

**What worked:**

```
function uploadToFtp(){

            $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  

            $destination='/httpdocs/images/'.$file_name;
            $source = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

            $this->load->library('ftp');
            $config['hostname'] = <..> // your hostname, username, password  

            $this->ftp->connect($config); 
            $this->ftp->upload($source, $destination, 'binary', 0775);
            $this->ftp->close(); 
 }
```

*Irrelevant notes / my personal opinion*:
This has to be the part I hate the most about programming - simple effective things are usually well hidden in a big chunks of irrelevant pre-written code in docs. Why should I use and 'port' big chunk of someone else's code to my project and then study how it works and what to do with it when I only need a one specific seemingly simple solution to add (NOT replace everything from scratch)?

Comment: It could be done with a HTML form; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php); is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok, so I get this html code: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  
</form>`

but how do I save/store the file location from this without replicating the butt-load of PHP code from that page that I don't need at all since I already have the function handling the file uploading?

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't need to use their method of "sending" the file, I only need file location and file-name, no need for "send" button at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with codeigniter itself: does the generated HTML page have such a form already? If so, you could use `$_FILES['file-input-field']['name']` server-side to get the original filename. There's no way to get the full file path of the file on the client, AFAIK.

Comment: The file that is uploaded is stored in a temporary file `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`.

Comment: Right. But how do I upload it then? I've ditched `move_uploaded_file()` and went with `$this->ftp->upload($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], '/httpdocs/images/'.$file_name, 'ascii', 0775);` - this gets the file uploaded correctly but fails to convert tmp to png which results in file being corrupted (yet with correct - png - extension). What am I doing wrong then?

Comment: Maybe don't use `ascii` for binary files?

Comment: haha, thanks, that did the trick.